# How to extract elements from pytube stream?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

I am working with pytube to write an automated scripts which helps me download a YouTube video. I wanted to get the itag number of the highest resolution video.

The method `get_highest_resolution()` returns the stream of the highest resolution video:

```
highest_resolution_stream = yt_obj.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').get_highest_resolution()
```

Its output looks like this:

```
<Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="25fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
```

Now I want to extract the value of itag from this pytube stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract `itag`, we just need to do use `<stream>.itag`:

```
highest_resolution_stream = yt_obj.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').get_highest_resolution()
my_itag = highest_resolution_stream.itag
```